# Replacing nuget packages with DLLs in Blazor server

Tags: blazor-server-side, nuget-package, dllimport

I have Blazor sever app that uses some nuget packges and works fine. Now I want to refernce DLLs /Assemblies instead of nuget packges, beacuase our build server cannot process nuget packages, and I must replace them with DLLs. I removed nuget packegs using Nutget package Manager in VS 2022 and tried to add DLLs, that I find them in lib directory of downloaded appropriate nuget packages, But I could not add refrences, becuase of the following error:

"The reference in invalid or unsupported".

Can anyone help me, to solve my Problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way and took the DLLs from ..\bin\debug (or ..\bin\release) and referenced them after removing nuget packages. It works for most of packages, except for Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices.

Now my problem has changed to an another one and is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77703160/the-windows-service-cannot-be-started)