# The Windows Service cannot be started

Tags: dll, build, windows-services, blazor-server-side, nuget-package

I have a Blazor Server application that works fine as a windows service. Now I want to refernce DLLs /Assemblies instead of nuget packges, beacuase our build server cannot process nuget packages. I am replacing them with DLLs, it works for most of packages, except for **Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices** package. Some of it's related DLLs cannot be reference, because of the following error:

"The reference in invalid or unsupported".

I tried to build the solution without these DLLs and copied them manually to the output directory. In this case, while DLLs in output directory are exacly the same as with nuget package, the windows service cannot be started and encountered an Execption as follows:

[image]

[image]